# Cleaning CDATA in xml through xslt

Tags: wordpress, xslt, rss, xhtml-1.0-strict, rss2

I am trying to transform RSS 2 coming from Wordpress into XHTML 1.0 Strict (using a cronjob and xsltproc); however, Wordpress inserts an `img` into the `CDATA` at the end of the `summary` element. The `img` has a `border` attribute, which is invalid in XHTML 1.0 Strict. Because it's CDATA, I assume that means I can't match it with my XSLT. I *can* say for certain that the `img` is always the last thing before the `CDATA` ends. I'd prefer to strip the `border` attr and keep the image, but I'd rather get rid of the element entirely than have invalid markup.

Is it possible to match inside CDATA using XSLT, perhaps using a string expression? If so, is that the right way to go here, or is there a better solution to be had?

Comment: First, there would be no elements, nor attributes, because that CDATA is just unparsed text. **Don't treat parseable data as unparsed data**. Second, every feed reader support Atom, wich treat mixed content properly.

Comment: similar problem has been discussed a while ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100482/xslt-rss-feed-combine-substring-before-and-substring-after

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember what CDATA means: "character data". Putting something in CDATA means: this might look like markup, but I don't want you to treat it as markup. So if that thing inside the CDATA looks like an `img` element, the CDATA is there to tell you not to be fooled - it's not an element at all. Having said that, you can of course process the text in the way you process any other character string, including passing it to an XML parser to be turned into a tree of nodes.

Comment: I wonder can `saxon:parse()` handle `CDATA` sections on the fly or should they be preprocessed by some other means?

Comment: Yes. saxon:parse() was invented to help people dig themselves out of exactly this hole - using CDATA to "hide" markup that should not have been hidden in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

CDATA is merely a text node, you can match it with `text()` template. Then you can use string functions to remove `border` attr from the text.